# how to check a remote port is open

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, command-line-arguments

Creating a windows application to check connection to a few servers. How it is possible to check weather there is a connection exist with the specified port on remote ip?

Is there any windows in-built command to check a remote port (command line)?

Don't know weather the port is a TCP or UDP port before checking. How it is possible .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out:  http://serverfault.com/questions/309357/ping-a-specific-port

Answer (score 2):

From my (german) blog: [enter link description here](http://www.codingfreaks.de/2013/01/05/pping-ein-ping-auf-port-ebene/)

**Update**: The tool supports UDP and multi-port-ping now too.

It'll return true, if the port is opened. This is old-fashioned code (without TPL), but it works.

```
var result = false;
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.ReceiveTimeout = timeout * 1000;
        client.SendTimeout = timeout * 1000;
        var asyncResult = client.BeginConnect(host, port, null, null);
        var waitHandle = asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle;
        try
        {
            if (!asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout), false))
            {
                // wait handle didn't came back in time
                client.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // The result was positiv
                result = client.Connected;
            }
            // ensure the ending-call
            client.EndConnect(asyncResult);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Ensure to close the wait handle.
            waitHandle.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
return result;
```

Comment: The port may be tcp Or Udp port. It works correctly for a tcp port. Connected to google (74.125.224.72) in port 80 and works correctly. But How it is possible for a port reserved for Udp (eg:60500)?

Comment: Why not just use a Socket, it seems unnecessary to use a TcpClient (with all its functionality) for something so simple..?

Comment: I didn't check it on UDP. Sorry.

Comment: @Friend: I updated my tool. New version is 1.1.3 and it now supports pinging to UDP-ports.

Comment: @AlexanderSchmidt thanks for the answer - it appears your tool has a broken link.